# Group queries in GraphQL (not "group by")

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

in my app there are many entities which get exposed by GraphQL. All that entities get  Resolvers and those have many methods (I think they are called "fields" in GraphQl). Since there is only one Query type allowed, I get an "endless" list of *fields* which belong to many different contexts, i.E.:

```
query {
 newsRss (...)
 newsCurrent (...)
 userById(...)
 weatherCurrent (...)
 weatherForecast(...)
 # ... many more
}
```

As you can see, there are still 3 different contexts here: news, users and weather. Now I can go on and prefix all fields ([contextName]FieldName), as I did in the example, but the list gets longer and longer.

Is there a way to "group" some of them together, if they relate to the same context? Like so, in case of the weather context:

```
query {
  weather {
     current(...)
     forecast(...)
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, may be you could use query filters: eg: weather(contextType: ContextTypeEnum) { if(contextType === 'Current' ) return currentWeather; ... }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to group them together , you need to have a type which contain all fields under the same context . Take weather as an example  , you need to have a type which contain `currentWeather` and `forecastWeather` field. Does this concept make sense to your application such that you can name it easily and users will not feel strange about it  ? If yes , you can change the schema to achieve your purpose.

On the other hand, if all fields of the same context actually return the same type but they just filtering different things, you can consider to define [arguments](https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#arguments) in the root query field to specify the condition that you want to filter , something like :

```
query {
   weather(type:CURRENT){}
}
```

and

```
query {
   weather(type:FORECAST){}
}
```

to query the current weather and forecast weather respectively.

So it is a question about how you design the schema.